# Doing an activity when mobile is silent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an android app which sends a message automatically when you get a miss call **but only when the mobile is silent** . I know how to send message when there is a miss call but i don't know to check whether the state of mobile is Silent or not .
Is it even possible to check the state of the mobile and if so how ??

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `AudioManager` like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch(audioManager.getRingerMode()){
   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
      // Phone is loud
      break;

   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
      // Phone is silent
      break;

   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
      // Phone is vibrating
      break;
}
```